# Removing file throws error: "Too many levels of symbolic links" on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, symbolic-link

After updating my linux-headers, I recognized problems with an old version that also blocked apt-get. I tried to remove the sources manually but I'm stuck at this point.

```
cd usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-36/drivers/pci/switch/Makefile/
sudo rm switch
```

throws the error

`rm: cannot remove 'switch': Too many levels of symbolic links`

Here is what I've tried, after googling around, but none of it worked:

```
sudo rm -r switch
sudo rm -R switch
sudo chmod 666 switch
sudo find -L ./ -mindepth 10
sudo unlink switch
```

the answer was always "Too many levels of symbolic links".

When I do ls -al I get

```
d????????? ? ?    ?       ?            ? switch
```

What is wrong with the file, or how can I diagnose it?
How can I delete it?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

After I rebooted the machine, I booted into the (initramfs) console. There [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/924547/774730) helped me. While repairing my sda1 with the command I had to repair INodes and some other blocks.

```
fsck /dev/sda1
```